# Large windows, dock bar, top bar, fonts

Tags: release-juno, display

After installing the latest elementary OS update, my windows, dock bar, top bar.. basically all desktop went big.

i've tried updating the scaling-factor to 0, 1, 2 like it says on other questions.... but seems it will do nothing, i still have the same big size.

I have no current themes applied.

Any help will be great, thanky you!!

my monitor resolution is 1024x768 which is setup correctly.

Current elementary version:

```
elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Built on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
GTK+ 3.22.30
```

Current Drivers:

```
sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for gcalderon:           
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Current scaling factor:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor
uint32 0
```

Current screen:

```
xrandr --query 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the screen to LoDPI on display settings>scaling factor?

Comment: hello!, yup but same thing, it will do nothing i still get this awful "resolution"

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot looks like a normal screen with 1024x768 resolution. Can you try to hold `Ctrl` and press `-`  repeatedly to make it smaller (`Ctrl` and `+` to make it bigger) to see if it has an effect?